# How do I add __format__ to a namedtuple in Python 3.5+?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, string-formatting

I'm working with code that was written for an earlier version of Python.

```
TensorShape = namedtuple('TensorShape', ['batch_size', 'channels', 'height', 'width'])
```

Later on, I have this (abridged) code:

```
s = [hdr, '-' * 94]
...
s.append('{:<20} {:<30} {:>20} {:>20}'.format(node.kind, node.name, data_shape,
                                                          tuple(out_shape)))
```

which blows up on `tuple(out_shape)` with the exception

```
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to tuple.__format__
```

because `out_shape` is a `TensorShape` and it doesn't have a `__format__` method defined.

So I'm changing the definition of `TensorShape` to

```
def format_tensorshape(format_spec):
    return format("{0} {1} {2} {3}")

TensorShape = namedtuple('TensorShape', ['batch_size', 'channels', 'height', 'width'])
TensorShape.__format__ = format_tensorshape
```

But this code still blows up downstream with the same exception.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What behavior do you expect from `{:>20}` when applied to a tuple?  Calling `tuple(out_shape)` is a no-op (`out_shape` is already a tuple), but you can simply call `str(out_shape)` if you want to display it as `(batch_size, channels, height, width)`.  And since that's a string, formatting directivesshould work as expected.

Comment: @larsks if you use str(out_shape) then you get the names of the class and methods as well as the values, not (batch_size, channels, height, width).

Comment: Right, `str(tuple(...))`, I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were on the right track -- just hook up the [two arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__format__) passed to `format_tensorshape` to your call to [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format):

```
import collections
def format_tensorshape(self, format_spec):
    return format("{0} {1} {2} {3}".format(*self), format_spec)

TensorShape = collections.namedtuple('TensorShape', ['batch_size', 'channels', 'height', 'width'])
TensorShape.__format__ = format_tensorshape

out_shape = TensorShape(1,2,3,4)
print('{:>20}'.format(out_shape))
```

yields

```
             1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use the formatting based on the string representation. That's possible with the `!s` conversion flag and because strings know how to interpret your formatting spec there is no need to create a custom `__format__` method for your `namedtuple`:

```
s.append('{:<20} {:<30} {:>20} {!s:>20}'.format(node.kind, node.name, data_shape,
                                                tuple(out_shape)))
#                               ^^---- here I added the !s
```

For example:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> TensorShape = namedtuple('TensorShape', ['batch_size', 'channels', 'height', 'width'])
>>> '{!s:>20}'.format(tuple(TensorShape(1,1,1,1)))
'        (1, 1, 1, 1)'
```